# Bi-directional Netty Server

Tags: java, web-services, sockets, netty, bidirectional

I have a server which needs to have bi-directional connection to clients and provide web services for few websites. 
In fact, webservice is a dealer which roots requests of web sites to clients.

The Scenario is:

1. Dealer starts it's web service and at the same time, listening on port 12345.
2. Client-A sends its username to port 12345 of dealer and keeps on listening on same port.
3. Dealer receives username, validates user and keep a connection to user.
4. Website-1 invokes doOperation(operation-X,User-A) from dealer's web service.
5. Dealer checks if user-A exists and send a request of "operation-X" to it.
6. User-A invokes "Operation-X" and sends back the result to dealer.
7. Dealer sends back the result to Website.

As you see in scenario, server needs to send unsolicited messages to clients and gets the respond immediately to serve web sites.

Firstly, I implemented a multi-threaded bidirectional socket solution, which worked fine for few clients but got performance problems and unfortunately we have more than 10k concurrent users.

Then, I found netty. It looks like a very promising solution. But it's asynchronous and event driven nature makes me worry. Some more, it seems to be unidirectional. http://apache-avro.679487.n3.nabble.com/Writing-Unsolicited-Messages-to-a-Connected-Netty-Client-td3675163.html

So the question is how to have an asynchronous handshaking ( something like : http://biasedbit.com/handshaking-tutorial-with-netty/ ) and then send the requests from dealer and get the result?

** Any feedback, advice and knowledge sharing is highly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Netty allows you to write any kind of protocol over TCP (actually, UDP and others as well, but let's stick to TCP). Once a TCP connection is established between two parties, any party can send data at any time, all according to a protocol of some kind.

The terms *client* and *server* does not really apply to an *established* TCP connection, but some protocols, like HTTP, does of course distinguish between the roles of the connection endpoints.

So, no, Netty is not unidirectional in the sense of the Avro link--that is probably a consequence of how Avro is using and exposing Netty functionality.

In your case, the "dealer" needs to manage the active channels that represents client connections and website connections, and coordinate messages sent and received between them. This is nothing special and you can probably find several similar examples and solutions floating around.

Comment: Dear forty two, Thanks. You gave me the confidence to go further. However, this is my very first project using netty and sockets and I couldn't find any sample. All I need is to find a working example to do POC and then write my own. Do you have or know any?

Comment: @NilNull Have a look at the [secure chat server example](http://netty.io/4.1/xref/io/netty/example/securechat/package-frame.html). I believe it has some of the characteristics you describe.

Comment: Ya, I have looked at it, the difference in my approach and netty's examples is, in my case, server needs to initiate the communication; it needs to find the channel's channel base on username and send a message to it. While in chat servers, server is answering to a client's request

Comment: A chat server is "initiating" the communication for all clients except the one that sends a message, so I really don't see the difference.

Comment: yes, that's the point, it initiates after recieving. I will need a public function to send message to a "specific user", anytime I want

Comment: So what's stopping you? Go ahead and write the code. If you run in to problems, come back with another question.

Comment: Please have a look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24969448/get-a-channel-send-a-request-and-get-result-in-netty